# redirect doesn't work while using example code

Tags: redirect, login, wp-login-form

I need a PHP page to be secured using wordpress login validation. Therefore I used this piece of code:

```
$args = array(
    'echo' => true,
    'redirect' => site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 
    'form_id' => 'loginform',
    'label_username' => __( 'Username' ),
    'label_password' => __( 'Password' ),
    'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
    'label_log_in' => __( 'Log In' ),
    'id_username' => 'user_login',
    'id_password' => 'user_pass',
    'id_remember' => 'rememberme',
    'id_submit' => 'wp-submit',
    'remember' => true,
    'value_username' => NULL,
    'value_remember' => false );

wp_login_form( $args );
```

but the redirect doesn't work.
When I login as admin user, I get redirected to the wp-admin page. When I login as a user, I get redirected to the front page. :-S

so, I tried this:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return home_url(site_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ));
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Didn’t work…

so I gave it a try with this (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

Complete code:

```
<?php
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );

require('../wp-load.php' );

get_header();

function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    //is there a user to check?
    global $user;
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if( in_array( "administrator", $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    }
    else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}

add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) 
{
    echo "Hello. You are logged in<br>";
    wp_loginout();
}
else
{
    echo "Hello. please login<br>";

    wp_login_form();
    echo"<a href=\"".wp_lostpassword_url( get_permalink() )."\" title=\"Lost Password\">I lost my password</a>";
}

get_footer(); 
?>
```

still...no success.

I am using WP version 3.8

===========================================

## added the functions.php file from the theme

```
<?php
require_once('inc/Sidebar.php');

register_nav_menu( 'top-menu', 'Top Menu' ); 

/*
 * Extending excerpt
 */
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 350;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );


//removing default "Continue Reading from Excerpt
function sbt_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
    return preg_replace('/<a[^>]+>Continue reading.*?<\/a>/i','',$output);
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'sbt_custom_excerpt_more', 20 );

//redirecting all users to dashboard (only subscribers on home)

function redirect_users($user_login, $user) {
    if(!current_user_can("subscriber")) {
        wp_redirect(get_admin_url());
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_users', 1, 2);

function wpse126853_redirect_to_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // instead of using $redirect_to we're redirecting back to $request
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse126853_redirect_to_request', 10, 3 );
?>
```

Comment: The first few lines tell me you want to protect a page and make it available for logged in user only and if that's true you can do it by  using [is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in). and if this is not what you want, then please add some more details on how do you want the above to behave?

Comment: Hi Maruti, I actually use 'is_user_logged_in' in the code to check if they are logged in or not. Problem is the redirection after login. When I'm not yet logged in. I can see the "Hello. please login" message. When I'm logged in and manually return to the same page and can see the "Hello. You are logged in" message and the log out link. All I want is, the users to be redirected to the same page as they started instead of the main page. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[`login_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)** filter to do this. One of the parameters is `$request`, which is the URL the user is coming from

Use the below in your active theme's **`functions.php`** file to make this work.

```
function wpse126853_redirect_to_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // instead of using $redirect_to we're redirecting back to $request
    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse126853_redirect_to_request', 10, 3 );
```

You can use the  filter for distinguishing redirect destinations by user roles. Take a look at the documentation for a deeper insight into that.

Comment: Hi Maruti, thanks for giving a hand. I've added function wpse126853_redirect_to_request( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    // instead of using $redirect_to we're redirecting back to $request
    return $request;
} to the functions.php (in the wp-includes directory) and added add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse126853_redirect_to_request', 10, 3 ); to the php script where I call wp_login_form(); after login I still get redirected to the main page... :-S

Comment: First, where are you adding the above? you need to add it in active theme's `functions.php` file and also remove `add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);` and the concerned function as you don't need it any more

Comment: ah...seems I added it to the wrong file. Now I added to code you gave to /httpdocs/wp-content/themes/thewebsite/functions.php But when I add the function to the functions.php file, something goes wrong and I only see a blank page (logged in or not). Please see the full functions.php file from the theme in my post above. Kind regards, Matthijs

Comment: comment out this line `add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_users', 1, 2);` and check and in the function `wp_redirect` should be followed by `exit;`. For details **[wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)**

Comment: added the exit; to function redirect_users($user_login, $user) {
    if(!current_user_can("subscriber")) {
        wp_redirect(get_admin_url());
  exit;
    }
} and commented out //add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_users', 1, 2); but as soon as I add the wpse126853_redirect_to_request function to the script, I get the blank page error.

Comment: Please go through this tutorial and the comments regarding the **[white screen of death](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-white-screen-of-death/)**

Comment: seems there is a conflict due to the "Wishlist Member" plugin. The plugin sets the users to be redirected to the homepage. I was not aware of this plugin (not my website). Thanks for all the  effort, I have to find a different way to handle this issue. Kind regards